# Updating subviews when data is updated

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm adding a set of labels on the screen based on contents in an array. Now, if I modify the array, what is the best way to update the labels?

Call `removeFromSuperView` on all the current labels, and then add the labels again based on the updated array?

I don't want to redraw the whole view, as this will reload the webpage in the WKWebView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // initialise a WKWebView and some others here

    var label: UILabel
    for i in 0..<myArray.count {
        label = UILabel(frame: ...)
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
    }

}
```

Comment: "What is the best way to x" questions are not a good fit for SO. However, I can say that removing your views and re-adding them when their content changes is a very **BAD** way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a reference for the labels in an array in your view controller and once your data array is modified, then you update the labels as needed:

```
var labels : [UILabel] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  // initialise a WKWebView and some others here

  var label: UILabel!
  for i in 0..<myArray.count {
    label = UILabel(frame: ...)
    scrollView.addSubview(label)
    //Add your labels to the array here.
    labels.append(label)
  }
}
```

Then once you need to update the labels according to the array you just use the labels array:

```
func updateMyLabels() {

  var label: UILabel!
  for i in 0..<myArray.count {
    label = labels[i]
    //Then you update your label as needed here
    label.frame = ...
    label.text = ...

    //If you need the Label UI to update you can call layout if needed
    label.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

Comment: The way I read this is: Perform as few changes to GUI as possible, just exactly what is necessary. So if I add or remove an element from the data array, I should add or remove a label at the end of the list of labels, and then iterate over all the labels and update text based on the array. In other words, look at the GUI as "established" once it's created, and manipulate it in the cheapest, most practical way. In contrast, do NOT delete and redraw GUI. But I have to ask why? Is it to prevent flickers?General optimisation? Doesn't iPhone have lots of power to redraw a few measly labels?

Comment: For both best practices and optmisation. 
First iPhone redraw power isn't all that good (if you want to easily test, use a table view with cells that add and remove subviews on the layout update methods, it'll get quite laggy). 
Second since your label object don't change it's superView you have no reason to remove and re add it. (Which is also costs quite some processing, [good reference for this](http://blog.benjamin-encz.de/post/disassembling-uikit-tintcolor-visitor/))

Answer (score 0):

The best way to give a unique tag to each label, and when your array modified only updates the labels which are affected. You can do it inside a loop.

For this, while creating labels you can give tag based on array index. When your array modified you should have some flag that this particular data is modified, you should loop through it and only update that label. You can get particular label by using the index of that item in array.

Comment: Nah tags are horrible.  Keeping them in a collection is better and quicker.